# Two arrays of objects need to filter the one based on the others key

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have two arrays of objects as shown below:

```
var array1 = [{"id": "-1","OwnerID": 777,"Admin": "true"},{"id": "-1","OwnerID": 555,"Admin": "true"},{"id": "-1","OwnerID": 444,"Admin": "true"},{"id": "-1","OwnerID": 222,"Admin": "true"},{"id": "-1","OwnerID": 111,"Admin": "true"}];

var array2 = [{"id": 777, "OwnerName": "Blah", "OwnerType": "Test"},{"id": 555, "OwnerName": "Blah", "OwnerType": "Test"},{"id": 444, "OwnerName": "Blah", "OwnerType": "BusinessMan"},{"id": 222, "OwnerName": "Blah", "OwnerType": "BusinessMan"},{"id": 111, "OwnerName": "Blah", "OwnerType": "BusinessMan"},{"id": 234, "OwnerName": "Blah", "OwnerType": "BusinessMan"},{"id": 432, "OwnerName": "Blah", "OwnerType": "Test"},{"id": 112, "OwnerName": "Blah", "OwnerType": "BusinessMan"},{"id": 114, "OwnerName": "Blah", "OwnerType": "Test"}]
```

I am needing to get a filtered array of array1 where the OwnerType in array2 is Test. The OwnerID in array1 is linked to id in array 2. I am looking to do this in as few lines as possible. Ideally, I mostly want to see if the array length is greater than 1 as the first array should only ever have one of that type. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

The desired output should be array1 looking something like:

```
[{"id": "-1","OwnerID": 777,"Admin": "true"},{"id": "-1","OwnerID": 555,"Admin": "true"}]
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the desired output of, `your_function(array1, array2)`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: @epascarello I have tried that I am just having a difficult time wrapping my head around how I may do that with 2 arrays :|

Comment: I'm confused by your question, you say "...where the OwnerType in array2 is Test". I don't see "Test" in your example nor your expected output array...

Comment: @Himmel yes, the determining factor for keeping an object in array 1 is if array2 has the key OwnerType: Test and to join the two arrays is array1's OwnerID and array2's id

Comment: @DaveChen I updated with the desired result

Comment: Did any of these answers solve your problem? If so please indicate so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I ended up using

```
array1.filter(ar1 => array2.filter(ar2 => ar2.OwnerType == 'Test' && ar2.id == ar1.OwnerID).length > 0).length > 1
```

Thanks everyone for the assist on this

Answer (score 0):

Two nested for cycles should solve it easily:

```
var array_result = [];

for(var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < array2.length; j++){
        if(array2[j].id == array1[i].OwnerID && array2[j].OwnerType == "Test")
            array_result.push(array1[i]);
    }
}
```

If array2 was an associative array, having the id as key, you could have a lot less complexity to the filtering.

Answer (score 0):

So first you want to return all of the objects in `array2` that have a matching `id` (`array1`) and `OwnerID` (`array2`) values.

```
// array of `OwnerID` values
var idArr = array1.map(function(obj) { return obj.OwnerID; });
```

Then you get only the objects from `array2` that have a matching `id` (with `array1` `OwnerID` AND that have an `OwnerType` of `Test`.

```
// filter array2 by matches
var matches = array2.map(function(obj) { 
  return idArr.indexOf(obj.id) > -1 && obj.OwnerType === 'Test'; 
});
```

The result, `matches`, will be an array of objects with the correct `id` and an `OwnerType` of `Test`.